Custom react nextjs hook
Trying to use a custom hook so as to separate CSR from SSR on the NAV, but when I Import the custom hook, it saying useMenuState is not a function. WHat could be the problem.
usemenustat.tsx
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export function useMenuState() {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleNav = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);
  };

  return { menuOpen, handleNav };
}

nav.tsx
import Image from "next/image";
import logo from "../../public/images/mainLogo.webp";
import Link from "next/link";
import { AiOutlineMenu, AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useMenuState } from "./clientsidecomponents";

interface useMenuState {
  menuOpen: boolean;
  handleNav: () => void;
}

const Navbar = () => {
  const { menuOpen, handleNav } = useMenuState();

  return (
    <nav className="fixed w-full h-24 shadow-xl bg-white">
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center h-full w-full px-4  2xl:px-16">
        <Link href="/">
          <Image
            src={logo}
            alt="logo"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            className="cursor-pointer"
            priority
          />
        </Link>
        <div className="hidden sm:flex">
          <ul className="hidden sm:flex">
            <Link href="/about">
              <li className="ml-10 uppercase hover:border-b text-xl">Why Us</li>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/contact">
              <li className="ml-10 uppercase hover:border-b text-xl">
                Contact Us
              </li>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/Services">
              <li className="ml-10 uppercase hover:border-b text-xl">
                Our Services
              </li>
            </Link>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div onClick={handleNav} className="sm:hidden cursor-pointer pl-24">
          <AiOutlineMenu size={25} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={
          menuOpen
            ? "fixed left 0 top-0 w-[65%] sm:hidden h-screen bg-[#ecf0f3] p-10 ease-in duration-500"
            : "fixed left-[-100%] top-0 p-10 ease-in duration-500"
        }
      >
        <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-end">
          <div onClick={handleNav} className="sm:hidden cursor-pointer pl-24">
            <AiOutlineClose size={25} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;


I have try to use different importing and exporting method but it not working
i still get same error saying the useMenuState is not a function.

Did you try adding "use client" in Navbar comp? It looks like your Nav component is running server side and your custom hook is running client side

Yes that was my intention. I want to make sure the navbar component is definately running on the server side that why i created the hook to be used on the client side. So that the handler function which required a use client would not affect the entier navbar component by forcing me to use "use client" on th component too
